# Update table records satisfying a condition related to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a date column of records satisfying following condition:

- Column STATION has to be the same as STATION from record with FILTER_NR = x
- AND STATUS IN (11, 12, 13)
- AND FILTER_NR != x

If x = 3 the UPDATE Statement, I'm looking for, should change the Table FILTER from:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
| FILTER_NR | PROBEDATE  | STATION |  STATUS |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
|         1 | 2011-06-01 |       1 |      10 |
|         2 | 2011-06-02 |       1 |      11 |
|         3 | 2011-06-03 |       1 |      12 |
|         4 | 2011-06-04 |       2 |      13 |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------+
```

to:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+
| FILTER_NR | PROBEDATE  | STATION |  STATUS  |
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+
|         1 | 2011-06-01 |       1 |       10 | -> not changed
|         2 | 2011-06-01 |       1 |       11 | -> changed
|         3 | 2011-06-03 |       1 |       12 | -> not changed
|         4 | 2011-06-04 |       2 |       13 | -> not changed
+-----------+------------+---------+----------+
```

I began with following SQL Statement, do you know how I can complete it?

```
UPDATE FILTER SET PROBEDATE = ADDDATE(PROBEDATE, -1)
WHERE FILTER_NR IN (...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE `FILTER` `F`
INNER JOIN `FILTER` `F1` ON `F1`.`FILTER_NR` = 3 AND `F1`.`STATION` = `F`.`STATION`
SET `F`.`PROBEDATE` = CURDATE()
WHERE `F`.`FILTER_NR` != 3
AND `F`.`STATUS` IN (11, 12, 13);
```

In my example, I've set PROBEDATE to the current date but please feel free to set it to what you might like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the SQL-Statement works! The SQL from @Andomar also does the right thing. Give me some time to decide which answer to accept.

Answer (score 2):

You could ty something like this:

```
UPDATE  FILTER 
SET     PROBEDATE = PROBEDATE - inteval 1 day
WHERE   STATUS IN (11,12,13)
        AND FILTER_NR != 3
        AND STATION IN
        (
        SELECT  STATION
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    FILTER
                ) as SubQueryAlias
        WHERE   FILTER_NR = 3
        )
```

Comment: At first glance I thought this should work, but MYSQL gives me the error: `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'FILTER' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Right, that's because you can't UPDATE and SELECT the same table

Comment: @Christian Ammer: Aliasing the table in another subquery usually solves that, edited in answer